# MSIX error: "You'll need a new app to open this ms-appinstaller link" ! HELP! Problem is in Sandbox

Tags: sqlite, sandbox, msix

Problem is in Sandbox when I try to install.
Win ver: Windows 10 2004 19041.153

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQl91.jpg